# How to enable lazy load in webix with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, lazy-loading, webix

I try to work with lazy load in webix. By default all data loading from database and it increases page loading time. Now I would like to ask you to help me in this problem. How can I make this work with webix and PHP? I tried some codes like that:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"datatable", 
  datafetch:50,
  datathrottle: 500,
  loadahead:100
});
```

In additionally to this, I also use pager in my datatable to paginate data. And I want to load next portion of data by pagination. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need not any extra config, just provide the url for the data loading

```
webix.ui({
    url:"data.php"
});
```

The key point here is the response of data.php, it must provide not all data but only part of it and info about total number of rows in the dataset.

http://docs.webix.com/desktop__plain_dynamic_loading.html#serversideresponse

You can use the same logic with paging ( no need to do anything special in the client side code, just enable the paging for the control )